# MySQL/PHP: How to determine most-recently past day of the week and time

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to determine the most recently past day of the week, based on any given moment.

**Example 1:** Given this moment — let's say Sun Oct 2 2016 15:30:30 EST — how do I determine the date of the most recently past Friday at 20:00:00 MST?

**Answer 1**: In this case, I'd be looking for Friday, Sept 30, 2016.

**Example 2**: What about the most recently past Sunday at 21:00:00 EST?

**Answer 2**: That'd be Sunday, Sep 25, 2016.

**Example 3**: What about the most recently past Sunday at 14:30:30 MST?

**Answer 3**: That'd be Sunday, Sep 25, 2016.

Comment: You could look at carbon which supports a semantic way of dealing with dates.

Comment: Hint: get day of the week, subtract the number you get, subtract 2 more days.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at the php DateTime API extension called Carbon.

https://packagist.org/packages/nesbot/carbon

If you install it via Composer you could simply write something like...

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Carbon\Carbon;

$knownDate = Carbon::create(2001, 5, 21, 12);          // create testing date
Carbon::setTestNow($knownDate);                        // set the mock
echo new Carbon('last friday');                        // 2001-05-18 00:00:00
```

Here is a great tutorial series by Alex from Codecourse on working with it...

[Carbon Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PD32vZEoGBI&index=1&list=PLfdtiltiRHWHGFP44atE9usZsKXtmaH3J)